# MQTT: How to send a message without to call loop_forever()

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm using MQTT since a while to monitor some channels I subscribed. Now I want to implement to send a message as reaction to a state. I got it running with the code below, where I just react in the on_message callback (code 1 at the end). But this code uses

```
loop_forever()
```

in the main code which is blocking.

What I would like to do is to just send a single message to MQTT. When I try the following (with all different loop-functions), nothing is received by the MQTT server:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
    mqtt_client.connect("192.168.178.204", 1883, 60)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username="test", password="test")

    mqtt_client.publish(topic='TEST', payload='CCCCCCCCC', retain=False)
    mqtt_client.loop_write()
    # mqtt_client.loop()
    # mqtt_client.loop_start()    

    mqtt_client.disconnect()
```

How can I send a message to MQTT which does not block the process?

---

Code 1:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, rc):
    topic_list = [("TEST_MS", 1)]
    if rc == 0:
        print("Successful connected and subscribed to: {}".format(topic_list))
    client.subscribe(topic_list)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload)
    client.publish(topic='TEST_MS2', payload=msg.payload, retain=False)


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("message published")


def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()

    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
    mqtt_client.on_publish = on_publish
    mqtt_client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

    mqtt_client.connect("192.168.178.204", 1883, 60)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username="test", password="test")

    # mqtt_client.publish(topic='TEST_MS', payload='CCCCCCCCC', retain=False)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()

    mqtt_client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send just a single message and then exit use the API specifically for that. [Docs here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#single)

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("paho/test/single", "payload", hostname="iot.eclipse.org")
```

Comment: This maintains a connection by itself. If a lot of messages are published using single() or multiple(), the connection to MQTT gets clogged up really fast.

Comment: As mentioned in the fist line, it's specifically for sending a single message, if you are sending lots of messages, then it's always going to be more efficient to reuse a single connection to the broker.